# Optimal query using indexes

Tags: index, sqlite, android

I have an sqlite table Task(type INT ,due_date LONG) where due_date is stored in epoch

```
TYPE     DUE_DATE
----    ----------
 1      1582038293 
 1      1485034292 
 2      1082048291 
 3      1982088290
```

I want to optimize a query to retrieve all type 1 tasks with a given range and type 2 & 3 tasks that are after some date.

Assuming :from and :to are variables -

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE (type=1 AND due_date >= :from AND due_date < :to) OR
(type=2 AND due_date >= :from) OR (type=3 AND due_date >= :from)
```

1. Would it be more optimal if I create an index for columns type & due_date?
2. Should I use 3 separate queries for each type if I use index?

Comment: 3 separate queries (with UNION ALL) guarantees that each separate query will be optimized independently. For a case with ORs I'm not sure... And true - the index by `(type, due_date)` is optimal

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Check all your queries with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).